# How to make my own library in java using slf4j, but the code using my lib will also use slf4j?

Tags: java

I'm writing a client server application : 2 different servers and a client. There is some shared code between the servers and the client and i exported all that code into another project. The shared code is using slf4j as is the nonshared part of my code. How can i proceed to include slf4j in each of my projects without any redundancy ?

The only thing that i can imagine is to include the slf4j lib into my shared lib, and then my projects will use the slf4j of my shared lib.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a build tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage your dependencies and include the artifacts you need in your projects as you need them.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for what it's worth, when building my shared library with intelliJ, the output jar does not contain the slf4j-ap-xxx.jar so everything was working as intended !